# Proplems with PHP installation with jpeg, png and freetype support

Tags: php, gd, libpng, libjpeg, freetype2

I'm setting up Typo3 on a Mac and it has an install tool that tells you what you need to change about your system in order to use it.

It said I needed to reinstall PHP with jpeg, png and freetype GD support.

So I downloaded the latest version of PHP and the jpeg, png and freetype libraries.

I configured, made and installed each library.

Then I configured PHP thusly:

```
./configure  --enable-exif --enable-ftp --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib --with-png-dir=/usr/lib --with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib --with-mysql --with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-gd=usr/lib
```

Then I made clean, made and installed PHP.

Then replaced php.ini with a copy of the new php.ini-development.

I thought I was done, but the Typo3 install tool still tells me I still need to set up jpeg, png and freetype support for PHP. Furthermore, going to info.php in my browser gives me information about the *previous* installation.

It's driving me crazy. What have I done wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are building from source? Also if you had an existing installation did you install over it or to another location? If the latter, did you change the apache config to point to the new php module?

Comment: I looked at a couple of packages, and couldn't find one that I was sure had the right support. It seemed easier just to do it manually, to be sure. Anyway, why not learn how to do these things yourself? I didn't indicate a new location, so I figured it would just go over the top of the old one. I'll be honest, I don't know what to look for to check if that's what happened.

Comment: Well the default location is normally set up in configure with various prefixes/target dirs (all with defaults). If your old install was not using the default layout, and you did not adjust the layout to match then you installed a second installation. Additionally if you are talking about setting up a server 99% of the time you are going to use the server OS's package manager to install, not build from source yourself (exceptions to that include running legacy versions needing to do things for very specific requirements).

Comment: The solution would be to find out where you installed this version, then figure out where its dropped the php module for apache and then to adjust the apache config to use that version of the module.

Comment: What specific file can I search for that will tell me where the new version is installed? What is the PHP module for Apache? And what is the Apache configuration file called? I thought it was httpd.conf, but I can't find anything in that file that is pointing toward a particular installation of PHP. Thanks.

Comment: Try going to your php source dir and doing `./configure --help` Should give you a list of options and possibly thier defualts. I think the switch for building the apache module is something like `--with-apxs2=/path/to/apache/source` but it should tell you. Also look at the main `README` and/or `INSTALL` for the php source... probably more info there. I think normally it installs things to `/usr/local` but i think that might be environment dependent. The Line you would be looking for in the httpd.conf would be `LoadModule path/to/something_php.so`